# how to solve this BVP $-\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2} +2u = 1$ $u(0)=u(1)=1$ using a Fourier sine series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I know how to solve a BVP in the form of
$$
-\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2} = 1
$$
using a Fourier sine series but i don't know how to go about solving
$$-\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2} +2u = 1
$$
My guess is that i have to use the same formulas but the function i plug in has to be different, it can't be 1 or i'd get the same fouier series as
$$-\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2} = 1$$
Thanks.

Comment: Found this. Hope it can be useful https://www.math24.net/fourier-series-applications-differential-equations/#example1

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$
v = 2u -1 \implies v'' = 2u''
$$
in the equation
$$
-\frac{1}{2}v'' +v =0 \implies v'' =2v
$$
which solution is quite easy